# Using WebView And Search Charm

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, webview, charms-bar

Is Posibble To Using Search Charm with WebView? uh, I'm using VB and VS 2012 For Windows 8 Apps. So Like This :

### Website : ex: example.com/search-0-{searchkeyword}

Search Charm -> Keyword -> Proceed To WebView -> replacing searchkeyowrd on WebView with keyword -> Load Page -> Done . 
Are it's possible? Sorry if you confused with this question. i'm new in here =D

Comment: Just for better understanding what you want:
1. Someone types something in Search Charm (ex. "xyz")
 2. The WebView shows example.com/search-0-xyz correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats possible. Suppose you are using search charm in the app and u type in some search parameters and in the searchActivated event you feed your data to through javascript using the invoke script method and add the data to your custon search engine inside the web view. I just shared  al logic but this can be possible only if you have a control over the web page. Then only you can invoke a function using the InvokeScript method and add text to your search engine. Let me know if you need some describing links.